# MixItUp vs PageSpeed Insigths

Tags: jquery, seo, pagespeed, mixitup

PageSpeed Insights says “Remove render-blocking scripts” and list jquery.mixitup.min.js :_(
But the script is included at the bottom of the page (and minified), and the functions that use MixItUp is also on the bottom of the page!
I don’t know what can I do.

Any suggestions please?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added defer attribute to the script tag and seems its working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any scripts within the page heading itself? How about things like Analytics or other tracking scripts? Those would be counted too.

Comment: Yes, I have Analytics script.

Comment: PageSpeed insights might be counting those. I wouldn't worry too much about the render blocking scripts unless you run a test on pingdom tools and find that those scripts are slowing the site down.